# Browse the tree of a website visually?

Tags: tree

Is there a way to see the tree of a website? Let's say: www.randomsite.com has a folder at root, named "idunno" which contains a file "hello.html". Is there a way to browse these like using explorer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. You can crawl all pages on the site and build a map of all the URLs and extract paths from that.
2. You can become Google and ask the site admin to send you a [sitemap.xml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps).

After that, you can write a tool which displays the map as a tree.

Background: Many web sites don't use folders on disk but databases to store their content. So on the web the notion "folder" doesn't always make sense.

Comment: What if a page i need is not linked in any of the public pages?

Comment: In this case (unless directory browsing is turned on) you won't be able to find out this file exists.

Comment: is there any program that does that, without having to make one myself?

Answer (score 3):

That would be a [sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Site_map)

Answer (score 2):

The web server has to have directory browsing turned on. Many sites turn it off for security purposes.